# Dumping sequence files with mahout seqdumper

Tags: hadoop, mahout

I'm trying to use seqdumper to dump a sequence file using the following command:

```
/opt/mahout/bin/mahout seqdumper -i ~/input_file -o ~/output
```

but it throws the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: WritableName can't load class: org.apache.mahout.clustering.WeightedPropertyVectorWritable
```

I've tried adding the mahout jars in the $MAHOUT_HOME/core/target directory to $HADOOP_CLASSPATH but to no avail.

Can anyone point in the right direction here?

EDIT:

I've also tried viewing the file through hdfs with

```
hadoop dfs -text /home/hduser/input_file
```

but I get the same error.

Comment: To use this with `hadoop` you do need to set `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` instead, yes. That's different. You still need to point to the right places for jar files and I don't think your install has them.

Comment: How do I point to the jars? I suppose you are referring to the ones created by running mvn install. I have them in core/target. I've found the WeightedPropertyVectorWritable in the core/classes folder, but how do I tell it how to load it?

Answer (score 1):

`core/target` doesn't contain classes. You are looking for `core/target/classes` at least. But, you should not need to do any such thing if `MAHOUT_HOME` is set correctly as the script already sets up the classpath.

Comment: I have $MAHOUT_HOME set to /opt/mahout which is where I have Mahout set up.

Comment: .. does it have the .jar files? or are they in subdirs like `core/target`? Look at the script, look at where it looks for JAR files, check that you haven't changed those things.